# SQL Query on Instructor table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck at the following SQL query:

**Find the name of the departments having more than 12 instructors.**

Ans should be given according to the given diagram.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
select dept_name
     , count(ID)
  from instructor 
group by dept_name
having count(ID) > 12
```

Comment: That's true, since `dept_name` is the foreign key anyway, a join to `department` could be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

use the `group by` and `having` clauses to filter on an aggregation function.

```
select d.dept_name
from department d
  inner join instructor i
    on i.dept_name = d.dept_name
group by d.dept_name
having count(*) > 12
```

Comment: with dept_table(dept_name,count) as
 (select dept_name,count(ID)
  from instructors
  group by dept_name)
select dept_name
from dept_table
where count>12;

Comment: @SadmanRizwan That's a lot of work just to avoid simply using `having`